# What is hosting space and why is it increasing every day?

Tags: php, mysql, web-hosting

My hosting's disk space is increasing every day and I just wanted to know, why? I don't upload new files, but it still gets increased by every day. Anyone knows?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you using dedicated or shared hosting?

Comment: @Jacob: dedicated

Comment: Have you looked at your logs recently?

Comment: you prob should ask your provider

Comment: Have you tried contacting your hosting provider and asking them?

Answer (score 2):

May be your logfiles are stored on your userv space (and count towards your quota). You should contact your hosting company or take a look at their admin panel to adjust log settings (how many days of backlog you want to keep, after how many days you want to compress or delete them).

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume you mean `disk usage` instead of `disk space`.

Usage will rise because of things like:

- log files;
- stats that are generated on the server;
- new entries in databases;
- etc.

Answer (score 0):

Many providers will start you out with a certain amount of storage and slowly increase it by a fixed amount after a certain time period has passed (i.e. they might start you out at 4GB and then add 50MB to your storage for every month you stay with them). Dreamhost does this, for example. That is, an increase in disk space is a good thing.

Comment: I believe he was implying that something is eating space everyday.